# Is there any function call to restart web application in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any function call to restart web application in c# ??

I mean the function call that will cause Application_End event in global.asax to execute

Comment: What are you `really` trying to do? Restart the IIS website? Recycle the application pool?

Comment: Are you using IIS, Apache? If Apache, which OS? Which version of .NET? Additional information goes a long way to help answer the question without wasting peoples time.

Comment: Am using Godaddy Windows hosting .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

[System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1332442581&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)

> Terminates the current application. The application restarts the next
>   time a request is received for it.